# Xpages using PostNewDocument event

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I'm trying to add a value to an editBox using the `PostNewDocument` event of the xpage, considering the fact that I want the field to have the respective value when it is opened - using a specific button.

I have tried 2 approaches:

< using Simple Action:

```
    <xp:dominoDocument var="Contr" formName="(fmFormularCIP)">
                <xp:this.postNewDocument>
                    <xp:setValue
                        binding="#{javascript:Contr.txt_codformularmain}">
                        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:"01"}]]></xp:this.value>
                    </xp:setValue>
                </xp:this.postNewDocument>
   </xp:dominoDocument>
```

( I'm getting: `Unable to execute the set value simple action because not allowed to set the value of a read only computed expression.` )

< using Script Editor ( server side )

```
<xp:dominoDocument var="Contr" formName="(fmFormularCIP)">
    <xp:this.postNewDocument><![CDATA[#{javascript:Contr.replaceItemValue("txt_codformularmain","01")}]]>
    </xp:this.postNewDocument>
</xp:dominoDocument>
```

( but still the field is "" )

My event handler from the button which opens the xpage:

```
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="complete" immediate="true">
           <xp:this.action> <xp:openPage name="/doc.xsp" target="newDocument"></xp:openPage> 
           </xp:this.action> 
    </xp:eventHandler>
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a working example for an XPage which sets the value to an edit field in postNewDocument event. The value is visible in edit field after opening the Xpage.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view
    xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
    <xp:this.data>
        <xp:dominoDocument
            var="Contr"
            formName="(fmFormularCIP)">
            <xp:this.postNewDocument><![CDATA[#{javascript:
                Contr.replaceItemValue("txt_codformularmain","01")}]]>
            </xp:this.postNewDocument>
        </xp:dominoDocument>
    </xp:this.data>
    <xp:inputText
        id="inputText1"
        value="#{Contr.txt_codformularmain}">
    </xp:inputText>
</xp:view>
```

The value itself can be set from **url** with `param.codvalue` if url has a codvalue parameter like `...&codvalue=01`or from a **scope variable** like `sessionScope.codvalue`.

Make sure you call this XPages **without** url parameter `?action=openDocument` or `?action=editDocument` as then the postNewDocument event doesn't get executed.

Comment: I use ?action=newDocument. is this a problem?

Comment: `?action=newDocument` is fine.

Comment: My event handler from the button which opens the xpage: <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
  refreshMode="complete" immediate="true">
  <xp:this.action>
   <xp:openPage name="/doc.xsp" target="newDocument"></xp:openPage>
  </xp:this.action>
 </xp:eventHandler>

Comment: My xpage data: <xp:this.data>
  <xp:dominoDocument var="Contr" formName="(fmFormularCIP)">
 <xp:this.postNewDocument><![CDATA[#{javascript:Contr.replaceItemValue("txt_codformularmain","01")}]]></xp:this.postNewDocument>
</xp:dominoDocument>
 </xp:this.data>

Comment: Still, the inputText is null when the xpage is empty.

Comment: My scenario is explained in my question: the xpage is opened via a button. in that case, it doesn't work.

Comment: I've added the code from the question in the custom control postNewDocument - as the field is on the custom control. And now it works. Thanks for your extra-explanations.

Comment: The reason why it didn't work for you was that string "txt_codf‌​ormularmain" in your code contained an additional invisible character after "f". Sometimes issues aren't fair... :)

Comment: Oh no, really?! I don't see any typo. Firstly, I've added the code in the xpage event, and it didn't work. Now, I've added it into the custom control event and it works.

Comment: Yes it's true. I analyzed it with an hex editor. Your string from comment has this invisible character whereas the string from question is fine. It's funny with coding sometimes...

Comment: I believe you... Funny, indeed. Btw, I've just copy the line of code from one your answer and paste-it into the PostNewDocument event of the xpage and still the value isn't displayed. On the other hand, placing it on the custom control event, it is working.